# Is it safe to run do-release-upgrade on a cloud VM?

Tags: ubuntu, azure, virtual-machines, cloud, ubuntu-17.10

I have a few Ubuntu VMs on Azure running Server 17.10 and I'm wondering if it's safe to upgrade them to 18.04.1 LTS using `do-release-upgrade`.

If so, what precautions should I take?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes

I just did this to about 110 EC2 instances. I actually did it from Ubuntu 14.04 through 16.04 and up to 18.04 using an automated the process for that many instances. It turns out it is possible to automate `do-release-upgrade`

If you want to be really safe, take a snapshot of the root disk before going forward.

Make a clone of your instance or spin up a test instance and do the upgrade. There are a lot of changes in Ubuntu from 14.04 to 18.04, a lot. A number of things broke, and SystemD changes a lot of default behavior.

But there are quite a bit fewer changes from 17.10 to 18.04, so I expect you to have a pretty reasonable time of it.

Comment: May I ask, how did you manage to automate the `do-release-upgrade` calls?

Comment: i've been meaning to post the scripts to github but i don't own them, so i need to clean them and post them to my own github, which i haven't had time to do. anyway, to sum up, it is a combination of `export DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive` and `do-release-upgrade -f  DistUpgradeViewNonInteractive`

Comment: I found both of those in the meantime, but good that it's recorded for posterity now. ;-)

Comment: @JDS > I just did this to about 110 EC2 instances. I actually did it from Ubuntu 14.04 through 16.04 and up to 18.04 using an automated the process for that many instances. It turns out it is possible to automate do-release-upgrade. How did you automate the process of do-release upgrade command without asking any questions or prompts.

Comment: @chandrasekhar I'll see if I can get my scripts into a publicly available github; they are owned by my company, not me, so I might not be able to

Comment: What do you mean "snapshot of the root disk" with Azure? How?

Comment: @pauljohn32 I did this in EC2; on EC2 you can make snapshots of any EBS volume, including the root disk. I don't know how to perform that type of operation on Azure

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on what you have installed. In general, I've come to prefer fresh installations of new OS versions rather than upgrading. There are a ton of fancy deployment and CM tools out there, and OS upgrades in general are complex operations even on "vanilla" installs.

Perhaps take a snapshot and try. Just make sure you can roll back quickly somehow.

Comment: Agree on fresh install. But moving user accounts and their programs not easy. Preserving permissions,  group membership looks tough.